# Mule 2.x filtering-router combining AND and OR filters

Tags: mule

We have a outbound filtering-router like:

```
        <filtering-router>
           <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="blah"
              connector-ref="blah"
              transformer-refs="BasePayloadToMsgEnvelope ObjectToJMSMessage">
              <ee:multi-transaction action="ALWAYS_JOIN"/>
           </jms:outbound-endpoint>
           <and-filter>
              <payload-type-filter expectedType="com.my.type"/>
              <expression-filter expression="payload.thingy.equals('31')"
                 evaluator="groovy" />
           </and-filter>
        </filtering-router>
```

But I'd like to say something like:

```
        <filtering-router>
           <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="blah"
              connector-ref="blah"
              transformer-refs="BasePayloadToMsgEnvelope ObjectToJMSMessage">
              <ee:multi-transaction action="ALWAYS_JOIN"/>
           </jms:outbound-endpoint>
           <and-filter>
              <payload-type-filter expectedType="com.my.type"/> OR <payload-type-filter expectedType="com.my.othertype"/>
              <expression-filter expression="payload.thingy.equals('31')"
                 evaluator="groovy" />
           </and-filter>
        </filtering-router>
```

Is this possible? I would think this would be possible using a Expression Evaluator with a type of payload-type but I'm unable to find an example of doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
<and-filter>
  <or-filter>
    <payload-type-filter expectedType="com.my.type"/>
    <payload-type-filter expectedType="com.my.othertype"/>
  </or-filter>
  <expression-filter expression="payload.thingy.equals('31')"
     evaluator="groovy" />
</and-filter>
```

Comment: Oh you can nest them? I didn't see any examples of that in the 2.2 documentation?

Comment: I have no idea where is the 2.2 doc nowadays, but this is the oldest doc available and it says they can be nested: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation-3.2/display/32X/Using+Filters#UsingFilters-LogicFilters

Comment: [2.2 docs are here](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation-3.2/display/MULE2USER/Using+Filters#UsingFilters-LogicFilters) and yep, it has the same note, thanks for pointing that out!